# Where can I download blender 2.79b?

Tags: windows

was wondering if there was a link to blender 2.79b as I can't seem to find a download link anywhere.

Comment: The most recent version is 2.79 and 2.8 is about to be released this year, here is the link https://www.blender.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

You may talk about blender 2.79b which can find in blender.org. There is no 2.97. Newest blender version is 2.80 beta.

Comment: Ignorance is the mother of all errors, if there is blender 2.79b and it is included in blender.org

Answer (score 0):

[Direct Download Win 64](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-windows64.msi/)

### Check blender for your platform

[image: BLENDER 2.79B]

[image: blender for all platforms]

[Blender.Org](https://www.blender.org/download/)